# iPhone MapKit: Accessibility of Annotations

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit, accessibility, voiceover

does anybody know how it is possible to add an accessibility label to a map annotation? I've tried adding it to the MKAnnotationView and the MKAnnotation but neither works. VoiceOver always only reads "pin" when an annotation is selected, while the original Maps application features the correct title when selecting an annotation.

Thanks and best regards,

Chris

Comment: Awesome question. I've been searching the web high and low for this info and this was the only thing I found. Just amazed that no one else has dealt with accessibility and ´MKAnnotationView´. Your question (and the answer) have helped me enormously. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `-mapView:viewForAnnotation:` set the `accessibilityValue` of your returned `MKAnnotationView` object.

Comment: Thanks Ortwin, I was only messing with the accessibilityLabel - but the Value did the trick!

Comment: FYI, setting `accessibilityLabel` works in iOS 8.2. Not sure what version it was fixed in though.